# express.js static html with get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

On the front page of my app, the user can register an account and then login. It is expressed as a login and register button on the front page which then show the appropriate form when either are clicked.

I would like to replace the two buttons with a log out button if the user is already logged in but I need to inform the client of that first.

In my index.js, I am serving static html like so

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I thought I could then do the following

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // inform the client if req.user isn't null
});
```

but the callback is never called

Comment: Because `express.static` is not `/` route. Try to navigate in `public/` url and see the difference.

Comment: `express.static()` is intended to serve static resources from `public` folder, and `var path = require('path')` is also required.

Comment: I understand a little better what it means to serve static resources now. What would you recommend for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Umm! i guess there would be a login/register form so there has to be two routes one with `.get()` and second one with `.post()`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // This is for navigation to the home page
}).post('/', function(req, res){
    // inform the client here about the req.body.user
});
```

and i guess you have set up this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); // for "formurlencoded"
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for "application/json"
```

if not then you have to load this module `require('body-parser')` first and require it only if you are using *express 4*.

Comment: Please reread the original question. 

I already have registrations working and I believe my logins also work; But I need to replace the login and register buttons on the first page with a log out button if the user is in fact logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

In my index.js, I have this

```
app.get('/isloggedin', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ loggedin: (req.user != null) });
});
```

And then I can just send a get request for /isloggedin and handle the result

```
$.get('/isloggedin', {}, function(data) {
    if (!data.loggedin) {
        // remove logged-in only elements
    } else {
        // remove logged-out only elements
    }
});
```